# Can't use `require` in Electron with TypeScript Create React App nor preload script

Tags: electron

I am trying to import Electron `ipcRenderer` within (Create)React(app) code but I get into obstacles:

1. Preload script not executed:

[image]

```
new BrowserWindow({
      titleBarStyle: "customButtonsOnHover",
      resizable: false,
      width: config.width,
      height: config.height,
      webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: false,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "..", "preload.js"),
      },
    })
```

2. I tried to add script to index.html instead

```
  <script>
      console.log(require);
  </script>
```

which results in:

> require is not defined

It appears due to webpack paths not working correctly? Which solution should work for importing electron ipcRenderer into React code?

Comment: you probably want to use `contextBridge`, see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also necessary to enable node for views:

```
 new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  })
```